# Multiple Record Insertion in Microsoft Access through VB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created DB within Access and given Data Type "Short Text."

Now I'm trying to prompt record into this table through Visual Basic. I wrote a code so far but need help to fix an error. I'm getting the compile error:

> Duplicate declaration in current scope

I can't figure it out what it is?

```
Option Compare Database

Sub arrayData()

Dim CustomerName() As Variant 
Dim num As Integer, dbs As Database, InsertRecord As String
Dim CustomerID As Long, num1 As Long, CustomerName As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb() 
CustomerID = 0
For num1 = 0 To 49999

CustomerID = CustomerID + 1
CustomerName = Array("Peter", "Mary")
CustomerAddress = Array("163 City Rd, SOUTHBANK", "65 Orange St, BENTLEIGH EAST")
CustomerPhoneAddress = Array("0416874963", "0478937534")
num = Int((200 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
CustomerName = CustomerName(num)
CustomerAddress = CustomerAddress(num)
CustomerPhoneNo = CustomerPhoneNo(num)
InsertRecord = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerPhoneNo) VALUES (" & "'" & CustomerID & "'" & "," & "'" & CustomerName & "'" & "," & "'" & CustomerAddress & "'" & "," & "'" & CustomerPhoneNo & "'" & ")"

dbs.Execute InsertRecord
Debug.Print CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerPhoneNo

Next

End Sub
```

What can I do in this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.

Comment: Two out of two tags incorrect - not bad!!  (Fixed)

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain it to me a bit?

Comment: The type of "Visual Basic" within MS Access is "Visual Basic for Applications".  "VB.Net" is an entirely different thing.  And the [access] tag you used has a description of "DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead. In computer security, general access control includes identification, authorization, authentication, access approval, and audit.", so is referring to something completely different to your question.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would explain the minor errors. Do you have compiler errors or does the code not behave as expected when it is run?

Comment: Please also edit the question to explain what the "minor errors" are, so that we don't have to guess.  (My first guess is the line continuation issues, my second guess is a subcript out of range error on `CustomerName = CustomerName(num)` after setting `num` using `num = Int((200 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)`.)

Comment: And my third guess is that your `[CustomerID]` field is not actually `"Short Text"`.  (It's strange to use a short text data type for an ID that starts off being a number, generated sequentially.)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gz3ulz This is the error I'm getting

Comment: Please edit the question if you have an image to include - that way it will be stored with the question itself, and not on a 3rd party website which may delete it in a couple of years time.  (Or just include the text of the error message in the question, and tell us which line the error occurs on.)

Answer (score 0):

The language you are using is "Visual Basic for Applications" (VBA). This language is line-oriented. It menas that one statement must fit on one single line, unless you are using a line continuation character (`_`) preceeded by at least one whitespace.

```
Dim CustomerID As Long, num1 As Long, CustomerName As String, CustomerAddress _
    As String, CustomerPhoneNo As String
```

But I would place the `Long` and `String` variables on separate lines and write:

```
Dim CustomerID As Long, num1 As Long
Dim CustomerName As String, CustomerAddress As String, CustomerPhoneNo As String
```

The second syntax error is in the `InsertRecord = "INSERT INTO ...` statement. same problem here. It shoul look like this:

```
    InsertRecord = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CustomerID,CustomerName," _
        & "CustomerAddress,CustomerPhoneNo) VALUES " _
        & "(" & "'" & CustomerID & "'" & "," & "'" & CustomerName & "'" & "," & "'" _
        & CustomerAddress & "'" & "," & "'" & CustomerPhoneNo & "'" & ")"
```

---

Also, what are the `- 0` and `+ 0` good for in `Int((200 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)`. The expression is equivalent to `Int(201 * Rnd)`.

---

After your edits it seems that you have no line continuations.

THE ERROR IS: You have 2 variables named `CustomerName`. Variable names must be unique:

```
Dim CustomerName() As Variant
Dim CustomerName As String
```

For instance, name the array `CustomerNames`:

```
Dim CustomerNames() As Variant
```

---

And you should indent your code. It makes it much easier to read.

```
Sub arrayData()
    Dim CustomerName() As Variant
    ...
    CustomerID = 0
    For num1 = 0 To 10
        CustomerID = CustomerID + 1
        ...
        Debug.Print CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerPhoneNo
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's why I insisted that the OP post the actual code - the revised version shows that there are no line continuations, so no line continuation characters needed.

Comment: I'm using everything in one single line. I don't think so it is a problem. Check the screenshot which I've given in comments. Anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: Well spotted on the `CustomerName`!!  My eyes didn't notice that one.  @MalikDraz **Please** edit your question to say what the "minor errors" are.